# MUI KeyboardDatePicker change styles of date input box

Tags: css, reactjs, date, material-ui, styles

Currently, I am trying to modify `KeyboardDatePicker` board color, size, font, padding, but unfortunately, all approaches don’t work. I tried so far:

1 . useStyles :

```
const useStyles = (params: any) =>
  makeStyles(() =>
    createStyles({
      componentStyle: {
        width: params.width ? params.width : 'auto',
        color: params.color ? params.color : 'inherit',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        fontSize: '12px',
        border: 'solid 2px #0070D8',
      },
    })
  );
```

Doesn’t override and a border appears on current `KeyboardDatePicker` border, size doesn’t change as well.

2 . Theme provide, it overrides calendar theme, but not `KeyboardDatePicker` date box.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

3 . Add styles into KeyboardDatePicker, it is the only working approach

```
style={{width:"246px",height:"44px"}}
```

How would you suggest modifying styles of `KeyboardDatePicker`, and yes style={} approach it's not the correct way to changes styles. p.s I am using Material-UI 4

My KeyboardDatesPicker:

```
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      margin="normal"
      id="date-picker-inline"
      defaultValue={props.value}
      value={selectedDate}
      required={props.required}
      showTodayButton={true}
      disableToolbar
      inputVariant="outlined"
      variant="inline"
      onChange={(selectedDate) => setSelectedDate(selectedDate)}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        "aria-label": "change date",
      }}
      keyboardIcon={<Icon icon={ICONS.Cool_icon} />}
      className={classes.componentStyle} // do not overide , but puts on top
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

`makeStyles` is a hook factory that returns a style hook (usually called `useStyles`), this is how it's used:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(...);
```

In your code, you define `useStyles` as a function that return `makeStyles` instead of telling `makeStyles` to create a new hook which doesn't make sense here, so change your code to the above. I also fixed the styles for you. The text color styles should be placed in `InputBase` component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    componentStyle: {
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      fontSize: "12px",
      width: (params) => (params.width ? params.width : "auto"),

      "& fieldset": {
        border: "solid 2px #0070D8"
      },
      "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
        height: (params) => (params.height ? params.height : "auto"),
        color: (params) => (params.color ? params.color : "inherit")
      }
    }
  })
);
```

```
const classes = useStyles({
  color: "red",
  width: 400,
  height: 80,
});
```

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  onChange={() => {}}
  inputVariant="outlined"
  InputProps={{
    className: classes.componentStyle
  }}
/>
```

If you want to style via `createMuiTheme`, here is the equivalent code. Note that you can't pass the component props to create dynamic styles unlike the `useStyles` approach above:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTextField: {
      root: {
        verticalAlign: "middle",
        fontSize: "12px",
        width: 150,
        "& fieldset": {
          border: "solid 2px #0070D8"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And it should work again. For reference, see [this](https://mui.com/styles/api/#examples-3) section to know how you can use `makeStyles` with component props.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Yes, but there are two borders, one is blue, other is grey is it possible to override grey border and change height size of the entire input box?

Comment: @BinaryTie I used the wrong selector. See my updated answer and codesandbox.

Comment: Agree with this answer, this is how we have built our component library.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need to write a custom hook like this `useStyles = (params: any) => ...`, the hook returned by `makeStyles` already accepts a [props param](https://v4.mui.com/styles/api/#returns-3).

When styling MUI components you need to check the API for each component to define the object you pass to `makeStyles`, in this case, the date picker component is a group of other MUI components, if you go to the API you'll see different props to pass to each individual component. To style the input you pass the classes returned by the useStyle hook in InputProps, with root rule as it is in the [Input API](https://v4.mui.com/api/input/#css), apply other rules if you need more specific styles.

```
const useInputStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: (props) => (props.width ? props.width : "auto"),
    color: (props) => (props.color ? props.color : "inherit"),
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    fontSize: "12px",
    border: "solid 2px #0070D8"
  }
});
...
    const inputClasses = useInputStyles()
...
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        ...
        InputProps={{ classes: inputClasses }}
      />
```

and to style the "board", not sure if you mean the popover, since you use the `inline` variant, you pass the styles in the PopoverProps, defining the styles in the `paper` rule as described in the [Popover API](https://v4.mui.com/api/popover/#css)

```
const usePopoverStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
});
...
    const popoverClasses = usePopoverStyles();
      ...
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        ...
        PopoverProps={{ classes: popoverClasses }}
      />
```

you can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-keyboarddatepicker-styles-sueqd?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it like this in TS, not a finished component, but I hope that this assists people. I am about to add `MuiFormLabel-root` etc to add more specific styling to the label.

```
const useDatePickerStyles = makeStyles<ITheme, ITextFieldStyleProps>((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    datePickerContainer: ({ isValid, isError }) => ({
      border: 'solid',
      borderRadius: 4,
      borderWidth: theme.mvf.border.width.thin,
      borderColor: theme.mvf.palette.border,
      ...(!isError && {
        '&:hover': {
          boxShadow: theme.mvf.boxShadow.primary,
          borderColor: theme.mvf.palette.primary.main,
        },
        ...(isValid && {
          color: theme.mvf.palette.primary.main,
          boxShadow: theme.mvf.boxShadow.primary,
          borderColor: theme.mvf.palette.primary.main,
        }),
      }),
      ...(isError && {
        color: theme.mvf.palette.error,
        boxShadow: theme.mvf.boxShadow.error,
        borderColor: theme.mvf.palette.error,
      }),
    }),
    datePicker: () => ({
      margin: theme.mvf.spacing.small,
    }),
 }),
);

export default useDatePickerStyles;
```

And get access to classes like so

```
const DatePicker: DatePickerType = ({
  id,
  onChange,
  format,
  value,
  label,
  errorMessage,
  placeholder,
  isVerticallyCentered,
  ...props
}: IDatePickerProps) => {
  const isValid = !errorMessage && !!value;

  const classes = useDatePickerStyles({
    isError: !!errorMessage,
    isVerticallyCentered,
    isValid,
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.datePickerContainer}>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          id={id}
          fullWidth
          maxDateMessage={''}
          minDateMessage={''}
          invalidDateMessage={''}
          className={classes.datePicker}
          label={isVerticallyCentered ? undefined : label} // don't show as label will be outside
          placeholder={placeholder}
          format={format} // of the displayed date
          emptyLabel={placeholder} // displayed value if empty
          name="datePicker"
          InputLabelProps={{
            className: classes.inputLabel,
          }}
          margin="normal"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          InputProps={{
            className: classes.inputPropsClasses,
            inputProps: { className: classes.textInput },
            disableUnderline: true,
          }}
          inputVariant="standard"
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            className: classes.calendarButton,
          }}
          {...props}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```